# SSG links issue using Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am a Svelte beginner, so bear with me (I suspect this is an easily solved issue).

I have been able to generate a static version of my site using the Static Site Generation outlined on this page: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static

However, all my links are broken. For example, it outputs a link like this:

```
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

when it should be:

```
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>.
```

So I need to figure out how to remove the starting slash and add .html to every link. Any advice? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should set [`trailingSlash`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash) to `'always'` in your layout to generate `index.html` files, which are more easily resolved by most web servers.

I do not know if there is any way to remove that slash at the beginning, it seems unintended. If you need a different base path, [there is a configuration for that](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths), though it still has to be added to links.